# How to get rid of ActivityManagerWrapper Error Google Login with Firebase com.miui.home?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am getting the following error on android Xiaomi phones with firebase google login. How do I fix this error ?

```
ActivityManagerWrapper  com.miui.home E  
getRecentTasks: taskId=165   userId=0   
baseIntent=Intent { 
act=android.intent.action.MAIN 
cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] 
flg=0x10000000 
cmp=com.firmname.MainActivity 
}
```

SHA-1 and SHA-256 finger prints added.